# how can i create zips with filename contain '/'

Tags: php, php-ziparchive

```
$zip->addFromString('filename_part1 / filenamepart2', $data);
```

The result is a dir named 'filename_part1' contain a file named 'filenamepart2'.Bu t i only want a file named 'filename_part1 / filenamepart2'.

Comment: why is there a slash to begin with? that's a bad character to work with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A '/' character is an illegal character to have in part of a file name, and it typically denotes a directory/file structure in most computer operating systems. I suggest not using a '/' in a file name.